# Python: program with nested loops not working

Tags: python, permutation

This program needs to find all permutations of a list by swapping elements using this rule - swap last element until it becomes first (for example 1, 2, 3, 4 becomes 1, 2, 4, 3 and so on until 4, 1, 2, 3), when it becomes the first element then you need to switch last 2 elements and do the same thing in opposite direction (swap first element until it becomes last and then swap first 2 elements and repeat), this is also known as Steinhaus - Johnson - Trotter algorithm.For some reason my implementation isn't working in Python and I'd like to know why and what do I need to do to make it work.

EDIT: By "not working" I mean that the program only prints list1 and does nothing else, the program can only be closed by "killing" it which means that it is stuck in infinite loop (this can be proven by printing all_permutations after appending list1 to all_permutations).

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3] #list that will be swapped
x = 3  #this is used for swapping

all_permutations = [] #list where permutations will be added

print(list1) #print list1 because it is the first permutation

while len(all_permutations) != 23:  #loop until all permutations are found (4! = 24 but since list1 is already 1 permutation we only need 23)
    x -= 1
    list1[x], list1[x+1] = list1[x+1], list1[x]
    all_permutations.append(list1)   

                               #code above swaps the last element until it becomes 1st in the list
    if x == 0:  #if last element becomes 1st
        list1[2], list1[3] = list1[3], list1[2]  #swap last 2 elements
        while x != 3:  #loop which swaps 1st element until it becomes the last element
            if len(all_permutations) == 23:  
                break
            else:
                continue
            x += 1
            list1[x-1], list1[x] = list1[x], list1[x-1]  
            all_permutations.append(list1)


        list1[0], list1[1] = list1[1], list1[0] #when loop is over (when 1st element becomes last) switch first 2 elements
        all_permutations.append(list1)


    else:
        continue



print(all_permutations) #print all permutations
```

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific than *"isn't working"*?

Comment: It only prints list1 (it's outside loop) and it is clear that the program is stuck in infinite loop (this can be proven by printing all_permutations right after appending list1 to all_permutations).

Comment: Please *edit the question* to provide all necessary information.

Comment: `all_permutations` contains multiple references to the same list object, which you keep modifying each time through the while loop.

Comment: @chepner so what do I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

```
while x != 3:  
    if len(all_permutations) == 23:  
        break
    else:
        continue
```

this piece of code right here will result in an infinite loop. If the length of `all_permutations` is not 23 it will hit the `continue` statement. This will send the program back to the beginning of the loop without modifying `x` or `all_permutations`.

I believe what you are looking for here is `pass` which does nothing. `continue` will move back to the beginning of the loop. So to fix this part of your program you can actually just get rid of the `else` altogether since the `break` will exit the loop anyway there is no need for it.

```
while x != 3:  
    if len(all_permutations) == 23:  
        break
    x += 1
    list1[x-1], list1[x] = list1[x], list1[x-1]  
    all_permutations.append(list1)
```

Or you could eliminate the `if` altogether:

```
while x != 3 or len(all_permutations) != 23:  
    x += 1
    list1[x-1], list1[x] = list1[x], list1[x-1]  
    all_permutations.append(list1)
```

Comment: Thanks but I still have 1 problem, I forgot to add 1 line of code so there will be duplicated permutations, here is what I forgot to add (with your and chepner's modifications)  http://pastebin.com/bY7ZznR1, what's weird is that this line of code will make the program execute forever and without it the program will run fine (but will of course find same permutations again), why is this line of code breaking the program?

Comment: The [review you just accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8710578) actually broke the OP's valid syntax...

Answer (score 0):

You are adding multiple references to the same list object to `all_permutations`, and that list object is modified each time through the loop. Instead, add a copy of the list so that you have a collection of distinct permutations.

```
all_permutations.append(list1[:])
```

This is one error; the infinite loop is due to the problem pointed out by IanAuld.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you new code at http://pastebin.com/bY7ZznR1 gets stuck in an infinite loop is that when `len(all_permutations) == 23` becomes True in the inner `while` loop you then append another list on line 30. And when control gets to the top of the outer loop `len(all_permutations) == 24`, so the loop continues to execute.

That's easy enough to fix, however your algorithm isn't quite correct. I've modified your code to generate permutations of lists of arbitrary size, and noticed that it gives the right results for lists of length 3 or 4, but not for lists of length 2 or 5; I didn't bother testing other sizes.

FWIW, here's a program that implements the recursive version of the Steinhaus - Johnson - Trotter algorithm. You may find it useful if you want to improve your iterative algorithm.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Generate permutations using the Steinhaus - Johnson - Trotter algorithm

    This generates permutations in the order known to bell ringers as
    "plain changes".
    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/31209826/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.07.03
'''

import sys

def sjt_permute(items):
    num = len(items)
    if num == 1:
        yield items[:1]
        return

    last = items[-1:]
    uprange = range(num)
    dnrange = uprange[::-1]
    descend = True
    for perm in sjt_permute(items[:-1]):
        rng = dnrange if descend else uprange
        for i in rng:
            yield perm[:i] + last + perm[i:]
        descend = not descend

def main():
    num = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 4
    items = range(num)
    for p in sjt_permute(items):
        print(p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 2]
[0, 3, 1, 2]
[3, 0, 1, 2]
[3, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 3, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 3, 1]
[0, 2, 1, 3]
[2, 0, 1, 3]
[2, 0, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 0, 1]
[3, 2, 0, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0]
[2, 3, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 3, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 0, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 3, 2, 0]
[3, 1, 2, 0]
[3, 1, 0, 2]
[1, 3, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 3, 2]
[1, 0, 2, 3]
```